# Jenkins Groovy string interpolation parses secret as ****

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to pass a jenkins secret to my DockerFile with the following Jenkins commands:

```
stages {
    stage('Build') {
        steps {
            withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'secretId', variable: 'NPMRC_FILE')]) {
                buildDocker dockerFilePath: 'Dockerfile',
                        compName: 'imageName',
                        dockerImage: 'imageName',
                        extraBuildArgs: "--build-arg VERSION=${env.RELEASE_VERSION}.${env.BUILD_NUMBER} --build-arg NPMRC_FILE=$NPMRC_FILE"
            }
            
        } 
    }
```

And here is my DockerFile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim  AS base
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y libgdiplus
RUN ls 
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
ARG VERSION
ARG NPMRC_FILE
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y curl
RUN apt-get install -y libpng-dev libjpeg-dev curl libxi6 build-essential libgl1-mesa-glx
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_14.x | bash -
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app/

COPY . code/
RUN echo $NPMRC_FILE > /root/.npmrc
RUN dotnet restore "code/pathToProject/projectName.csproj"
RUN dotnet build "code/pathToProject/projectName.csproj" --no-restore /p:Version=$VERSION /p:Company=Company /p:"Copyright=Copyright%20©%20%202019"
RUN dotnet publish "code/pathToProject/projectName.csproj" --no-build -o /app/out/
RUN ls -lR out

FROM base AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out ./
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "projectName.dll"]
```

But when inspect the .npmrc file I get **** and a warnging:  Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.

Any help would be great.

Comment: Did you figure out how to securely pass your credentials? I kinda have the same issue as you. Using single quotes and no brackets doesn't help either, as directed in the docs.

Answer (score 1):

don't interpolate secret values. escape `$` in `$NPMRC_FILE` to make it processed as environment variable.

in your case:

```
withCredentials([file(credentialsId: 'secretId', variable: 'NPMRC_FILE')]) {
  buildDocker ...
  "... NPMRC_FILE=\$NPMRC_FILE"
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately it still gets passed as '****'

Comment: How do you know? Do you still have warning?

Comment: Actually I didn’t. But when I inspect the file it outputs ****

Comment: Are you inspecting file through Jenkins?

Comment: Through the Dockerfile

Comment: what does it mean "Through the Dockerfile" ?

Comment: After step RUN echo $NPMRC_FILE > /root/.npmrc I RUN cat /root/.npmrc and it outputs ****

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239166/discussion-between-ben-and-daggett).

Comment: anything inside jenkins that tries to print any secret will be converted to '***' for security reason. the only way to check - get into the container and check the file.